# How to get the identity values of records that were newly inserted or already existing?

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, sql-server-2012, identity

I have the following SQL so far...

```
-- SETUP MY SQL
DECLARE @NewUsers    TABLE (Username VARCHAR(32), Name VARCHAR(32))
DECLARE @UserResults TABLE (UserName VARCHAR(32), UserId INT)

INSERT INTO @NewUsers (Username, Name)
VALUES ('johndoe', 'John Doe'),
       ('janedoe', 'Jane Doe'),
       ('mrsmith', 'Mr Smith') -- This guy already exists in the DB though...

-- INSERT STATEMENT

INSERT INTO User (Username, Name)
    SELECT new.Username, new.Name
    FROM @NewUsers new
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.User WHERE User.Username = new.Username)
```

---

What I want to do is get the resulting `@@IDENTITY` values to use in another insert statement later on in my SQL, but I want to get **ALL** of the identities, including the user that already existed and was not inserted. I know I can always do another select statement afterwards, but I'm not sure that that is the best way?

```
INSERT INTO @UserResults (UserResults, UserId)
    SELECT Username, UserId
    FROM User
    INNER JOIN @NewUsers new ON new.Username = User.Username
```

I think there is a more efficient way to populate the Results table with all the identities (newly inserted and/or existing) using the `OUTPUT` clause, but I'm not sure... is there a better way than the way I'm doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd like to see all identities, even of rows that already existed.  That means the `output` clause alone won't be sufficient.  You'll need a new query afterwards anyway:

```
select  u.id
from    @NewUsers nu
join    [User] u
on      u.Username = nu.Username
```

The pages with relevant users will be in memory because of the earlier "not exists" subquery.  So from an efficiency standpoint, this is nothing to worry about.

Comment: Yes I'd agree.  Today's databases are very fast.  It's best to ignore performance considerations until there's an actual performance issue.  The #1 consideration should be clarity, and your current approach is simple and good.